# In AngularJs why does one scope variable update when changed, and another very similar variable does not?

Tags: angularjs

I have an `ItemsService` that supplies an array of items to a pair of controllers/views.

In the first case (list view) a change in one of the items in the service results in a change in the UI - all good.

In the second case (detail view) the items binds fine but it does not update if the item changes in the service.

What have I missed?

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jlk2xFfry4N8Wqfw31Em?p=preview

Service:

```
app.factory('ItemsService', function ($rootScope) {

    // omitted code to update items - this works fine

    var itemsById = [];
    var itemsArray = [];

    function updateItems(itemUpdate) {
        itemsById[itemUpdate.Id] = itemUpdate;

        while (itemsArray.length > 0) {
            itemsArray.pop();
        }

        for (var key in itemsById) {
            itemsArray.push(itemsById[key]);
        };
    }

    return {
        items: itemsArray,
        itemsById: itemsById,
    }
});
```

Controller for listing items:

```
app.controller('ItemsController', function ($scope, ItemsService) {
    $scope.items = ItemsService.items;
});
```

List view:

```
<table class="table" data-ng-controller="ItemsController">
    <tr data-ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Controller for the detail view:

```
//$stateParams is part of Angular UI Routing - this works because the correct item is selected and displayed - it just doesn't update
app.controller('ItemController', function ($scope, $stateParams, ItemService) {
    $scope.item = ItemService.itemsById[$stateParams.id];
});
```

Detail view:

```
<div data-ng-controller="ItemController">
    {{item.Name}}
</div>
```

**Edit**

If I wrap the call to assign the item in the second case in a function it works:

```
app.controller('ItemController', function ($scope, $stateParams, ItemService) {
    $scope.item = function () { return ItemService.itemsById[$stateParams.id]; }
});
```

Detail view:

```
<div data-ng-controller="ItemController">
    {{item().Name}}
</div>
```

But my understanding is that it's bad practice to bind to function calls like this..

Comment: Please provide the jsfiddle or plunker version. It can save our time to test and find out the problem.

Comment: will likely do better leaving items array alone and not rebuilding it each time. For specific item, just iterate array and return the object

Comment: @hutingung - Unfortunately I can't, it's bound to a backend service that provides the items. All the relevant code is here though.

Comment: @charlietfl - that isn't the issue. The items array works fine in the list view. It's when I get an item from the associative array by id that updates then fail to propagate.

Comment: that's why I'm saying to pull from same master array. Also javascript has no associative arrays. You are losing reference between the 2 somehow

Comment: @glasswall, I means you create the plunker for the front end javascript. You can always mock service to return static json data.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have associative arrays? Huh? http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1441-javascript-data-structures-the-associative-array.html

Comment: @hutingung - plunker created http://plnkr.co/edit/Jlk2xFfry4N8Wqfw31Em?p=preview

Comment: @glasswall, what you mean by changes in one of the item? I forked the plunker that you created. http://plnkr.co/edit/AIpqLR6x4cYoADcyvA3H?p=preview . Is it ItemService.updateItems work in ItemsController but not in ItemController? If yes, please update your question.

Comment: @glasswall, or you mean update the value in ui for that particular item.. http://plnkr.co/edit/MRH5pHHRDAErqx7iREYK?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually a lot of things going in in your sample code at the same time, and I wasn't sure what part of the code was actually what you cared about, and what part was just for the demonstration.

Here's a working Plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/mjUtRSfFwYLGPC17O0st?p=preview

I changed a few things. First, in the factory you were returning hard-coded arrays of objects, but the way you were initializing them made each object unique, not the same element. So updating them would have updated only one copy at each spot:

```
return {
    items: [{Id: '1', Name: 'TestItem1'}, {Id: '2', Name: 'TestItem2'}],
    itemsById: {'1': {Id: '1', Name: 'TestItem1'}, '2': {Id: '2', Name: 'TestItem2'} },
}
```

Maybe you just did this for demo purposes? But in your update routine as you mutate these arrays there's no way for AngularJS to keep track of those changes because they'll all be pointing to different objects on every call.

Next, I changed the service from a Factory to a Service. They can both work, but I find the Service pattern is often easier to understand when you're making things like this - singletons in front of an API. Javascript is VERY susceptible to even small mistakes in how references to objects are taken. For instance, when you do this:

```
itemsById[itemUpdate.Id] = itemUpdate;
```

this will get you into a lot of trouble, especially in Angular. What tends to happen is elsewhere you do something like this:

```
var myItem = ThatService.itemsById[123];
```

But now you have a reference to the old copy. When you update the entry with the new copy, your screen will not update. This is because myItem points to the old copy even though you've updated the array that holds the items. That is, a reference in JS points to the destination object, not to its slot in its storage collection. Updating the storage collection needs to be done more like:

```
myCollection[Id] = myCollection[Id] || {};
angular.extend(myCollection[Id], myNewData);
```

This way no matter who has a reference to the object, it will get the update desired.

Please take a look at the Plunkr and let me know if you have any questions. I'm happy to comment back if you need more specifics about your exact use case!

Comment: Chad - you're a star. I figured it was something to do with references, but didn't spot that issue. Your last two lines of code fixed it, but would you mind just explaining the syntax, what's actually going on here?

Comment: Ok - the first line is null coalescing, the second line adds all the properties from `myNewData` to the item in that array location. Many thanks Chad.

Comment: By the way, is there a tool for helping debug reference issue like this?

Comment: I haven't found one specific to Angular, unfortunately. I have found that ESLint is really helpful in the build process though. The standard pattern that leads to this is assignment to an object directly, like `myObj = {}` or `myArr = []`. It's super easy to scan for and warn/error out when they're found. That's what I do.